# Stirling Engine - Geometery, Timing, Compression Ratio, Seals

Tags: thermodynamics

Inspired by this video: [Making the World's Smallest Beam Stirling Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCjwlSX-tsY&ab_channel=ChronovaEngineering), I wish to make a small Stirling engine like the one shown in the video.

Based off that video, I have modelled all the parts in CAD software but before I machine them, I'd like some feedback on my model since I don't have any experience designing engines. I only visually replicated what I saw in the YouTube video since that engine seems to run very well.

- Is the geometry optimal?
- Is the timing optimal?
- Are the compression ratios optimal?

[image: Stirling Engine]

Also, I am unable to figure out if the tolerances marked in blue and red should be gas tight or loose.

[image: Stirling Engine]

Cheers

Comment: To determine compression ratios, dimension are required.

Comment: Based on the cycle that operates this engine, you should be able to state the type of seal required at the location you highlighted in red.If you can't then you  need to make sure you understand the cycle and what happens when.